# What are the bones of a Powerful CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system

I'm working in a company to improve their own market CMS, if you had the opportunity to build your own CMS (revision of existing CMS) what steps would you take?

As far as I know these things can be most important:

- template engine (caching ability)
- a php framework (ZEND)
- a javascript Framework (Jquery)
- OOP coding style
- Security Issues  (I have no idea how to make this happen, trying to obey security notes in writing php is enough or we should use any existing security)
- an auto updater script (wondering how I can do it)

Comment: I'd say give modx a spin, since (in my books) they seem to have the right idea when it comes to extensibility.
A lot of CMSes are great at the their niche, are really simple, or are loaded with modules, but few make it easy to extend on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See how the POWER of frameworks is calculated and compared.](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) Thanks

Core points include:

**PHP4

PHP5

MVC

Multiple DB's

ORM

DB Objects

Templates

Caching

Validation

Ajax

Auth Module

Modules

EDP
Routing**

Answer (score 2):

...and what about code maintainability?

And Documentation (even if youre the only working on the project: will you remember what that function does at 3 years from now?)

Caching, if is it possible, use memcached or apc to reduces the database hits, not only in the templating behavior.

Extensibility. Every famous cms nowadays have modules/plugins: write your code in order to allow them to be used ([hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/hooks) functions?). Dont see the plugin as an 'external' thing only: you will be glato to create a module to satisfy your costumer needs, instead of completely rebuild a part of your CMS.

Whitelist for security, htmlpurifier for html fields.

Follow strictly the MVC conventions (..even if this point is potentially subjective).